# System.Threading.Tasks equivalent in UNIX and C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, unix, multicore

I've read this article about multi-core processing:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/usisvde/2009/10/24/how-to-get-started-with-multi-core-parallel-processing-you-can-use/

In .NET Framework 4 there is a method called `System.Threading.Tasks` that can manage the available logical processors. Is there any way to do quite the same in C++ and UNIX without .NET Framework ?

By the same I mean avoid the overheard of the threads.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org.

Comment: Take a look also at QtConcurrent that works for unix mac and windows http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent-index.html

Comment: Nice! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what the .NET does but `std::async` / `std::future` allows parallel queuing of tasks.

Comment: Oh, very interesting! I think you're right, it seems that `std::async` is based in some way on `std::thread::hardware_concurrency`. Thank you for this quick answer!

Answer (score 1):

No, there’s no built-in direct equivalent.

std::async [launches a new thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32517201/126995) for every asynchronous task, i.e. very slow when you have many short operations.

You can look for third-party C++ thread pool implementation.

Or you can switch to some higher-level API. I have positive experience with [OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP), it’s included in most C++ compilers, and under the hood it does have a thread pool with a scheduler. I’ve heard [Intel’s TBB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threading_Building_Blocks) is also good.