# prevent sleep_for from blocking background thread

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous, thread-sleep

I'm writing in pure c++11 and want to do a simple 'wait x seconds and turn on a member variable' after turning it off. The member variable of the class in this example is a flag for 'animating'.

```
        cout << "stop animating!" << endl;
        this->animating = false;

        async(launch::async, [this] ()
        {
            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds{8});
            this->animating = true;
            std::cout << "start animating!" << std::endl;               
        });
        cout << "i'm here" << endl;
```

the ***this_thread::sleep_for*** blocks the entire program from continuing on (even though it is inside an async thread). because i dont see "I'm here" 8 seconds later. If the above code worked as intended, i would see "I'm here" immediately after "stop animating". This blocking is a problem for me because it locks up everything I care about like continuing to process 'input' like keyboard events, and the program also stops 'drawing' other objects on the screen.

Does anyone know how to achieve a simple delayed and async change of a member variable using standard c++11 (no frameworks like boost please)

in iOS it is very simple:

```
// Delay execution of my block for 10 seconds.
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 10 * NSEC_PER_SEC), 
dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
{
    //do whatever, 10 seconds later
});
```

Comment: Either use `std::thread([this](){...}).detach();` instead or try saving the result std::future and make sure it doesn't go out of scope.

Comment: yes. this appears to work, even better than keeping track of the auto future returned from async. i think this is the answer

Comment: Maybe have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32517201/3972710). As  user2176127 mentioned it you may save the std::future otherwise its destructor waits for its result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per @user2176127 's comment - have you tried this? :

```
cout << "stop animating!" << endl;
this->animating = false;

std::thread delay_thread(
    [this]() {
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds{8});
        this->animating = true;
        std::cout << "start animating!" << std::endl;               
    }
);
delay_thread.detach();
std::cout << "I'm here" << std::endl;
```

Also note you likely need to wrap the `animating` member in an [`std::atomic<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic), i.e. if it was `bool` it now becomes an `std::atomic<bool>`, so as to ensure your main thread notices the change when it actually happens. (Using `volatile` won't help.)

Comment: `volatile` isn't necessary. Unless you write low level code `volatile` is almost always useless. If you want to be pedantic about the `animating` variable use `std::atomic<bool>`.

Comment: In C++ `volatile` has nothing to do with thread safety. While it will probably work in practice, you really need `atomic<bool>`, otherwise it's UB.

Comment: Keyword `volatile` is for use with memory-mapped hardware only.

Comment: @user2176127: Please note the recent (volatile -> atomic).

Comment: @JiveDadson: Signal handling.