# Why std::future is different returned from std::packaged_task and std::async?

Tags: c++, c++14, stdasync, packaged-task, std-future

I got to know the reason that `future` returned from `std::async` has some special shared state through which `wait on returned future` happened in the destructor of future. But when we use `std::pakaged_task`, its future does not exhibit the same behavior.
To complete a packaged task, you have to explicitly call `get()` on `future` object from `packaged_task`.

Now my questions are:

1. What could be the internal implementation of future (thinking `std::async` vs `std::packaged_task`)?
2. Why the same behavior was not applied to `future` returned from `std::packaged_task`? Or, in other words, how is the same behavior stopped for `std::packaged_task`  `future`?

To see the context, please see the code below:

It does not wait to finish `countdown` task. However, if I un-comment `//   int value = ret.get();`, it would finish `countdown` and is obvious because we are literally blocking on returned future.

```
    // packaged_task example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <future>       // std::packaged_task, std::future
#include <chrono>       // std::chrono::seconds
#include <thread>       // std::thread, std::this_thread::sleep_for

// count down taking a second for each value:
int countdown (int from, int to) {
  for (int i=from; i!=to; --i) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
  }
  std::cout << "Lift off!" <<std::endl;
  return from-to;
}

int main ()
{
   std::cout << "Start " << std::endl;
  std::packaged_task<int(int,int)> tsk (countdown);   // set up packaged_task
  std::future<int> ret = tsk.get_future();            // get future

  std::thread th (std::move(tsk),10,0);   // spawn thread to count down from 10 to 0

//   int value = ret.get();                  // wait for the task to finish and get result

  std::cout << "The countdown lasted for " << std::endl;//<< value << " seconds.\n";

  th.detach();   

  return 0;
}
```

If I use `std::async` to execute task `countdown` on another thread, no matter if I use `get()` on returned `future` object or *not*, it will always finish the task.

```
// packaged_task example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <future>       // std::packaged_task, std::future
#include <chrono>       // std::chrono::seconds
#include <thread>       // std::thread, std::this_thread::sleep_for

    // count down taking a second for each value:
    int countdown (int from, int to) {
      for (int i=from; i!=to; --i) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
      }
      std::cout << "Lift off!" <<std::endl;
      return from-to;
    }
    
    int main ()
    {
       std::cout << "Start " << std::endl;
      std::packaged_task<int(int,int)> tsk (countdown);   // set up packaged_task
      std::future<int> ret = tsk.get_future();            // get future
    
      auto fut = std::async(std::move(tsk), 10, 0);   

    
    //   int value = fut.get();                  // wait for the task to finish and get result
    
      std::cout << "The countdown lasted for " << std::endl;//<< value << " seconds.\n";

      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: In first program you are not waiting for thread to run, main is exiting even before that thread starts.

Comment: @Ayub In second program also, I am not waiting. But program itself waits in future destructor. 
and That is my question about  difference in  behavior of both future (from program 1 and program 2)

Comment: You may try playing with std::launch::async (or ...::deferred) in std::async. The `async` destructor will wait for its future to complete *only* if it has started.

Comment: @olepinto your observation seems to be right but it does not answer my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::async` has definite knowledge of how and where the task it is given is executed. That is its job: to *execute* the task. To do that, it has to actually put it somewhere. That somewhere could be a thread pool, a newly created thread, or in a place to be executed by whomever destroys the `future`.

Because `async` knows how the function will be executed, it has 100% of the information it needs to build a mechanism that can communicate when that potentially asynchronous execution has concluded, as well as to ensure that if you destroy the `future`, then whatever mechanism that's going to execute that function will eventually get around to actually executing it. After all, it knows what that mechanism is.

But `packaged_task` *doesn't*. All `packaged_task` does is store a callable object which can be called with the given arguments, create a `promise` with the type of the function's return value, and provide a means to both get a `future` and to execute the function that generates the value.

When and where the task actually gets executed is none of `packaged_task`'s business. Without that knowledge, the synchronization needed to make `future`'s destructor synchronize with the task simply can't be built.

Let's say you want to execute the task on a freshly-created thread. OK, so to synchronize its execution with the `future`'s destruction, you'd need a mutex which the destructor will block on until the task thread finishes.

But what if you want to execute the task in the same thread as the caller of the `future`'s destructor? Well, then you *can't* use a mutex to synchronize that since it all on the same thread. Instead, you need to make the destructor invoke the task. That's a completely different mechanism, and it is contingent on how you plan to execute.

Because `packaged_task` doesn't know how you intend to execute it, it cannot do any of that.

Note that this is not unique to `packaged_task`. *All* `future`s created from a user-created `promise` object will not have the special property of `async`'s `future`s.

So the question really ought to be why `async` works this way, not why everyone else *doesn't*.

If you want to know that, it's because of two competing needs: `async` needed to be a high-level, brain-dead simple way to get asynchronous execution (for which sychronization-on-destruction makes sense), and nobody wanted to create a new `future` type that was identical to the existing one save for the behavior of its destructor. So they decided to overload how `future` works, complicating its implementation and usage.

Answer (score 8):

@Nicol Bolas has [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64363727/415784) this question quite satisfactorily. So I'll attempt to answer the question slightly from different perspective, elaborating the points already mentioned by @Nicol Bolas.

## The design of related things and their goals

Consider this simple function which we want to execute, in various ways:

```cpp
int add(int a, int b) {
    std::cout << "adding: " << a << ", "<< b << std::endl;
    return a + b;
}
```

Forget `std::packaged_task`, `std ::future` and `std::async` for a while, let's take one step back and revisit how `std::function` works — in particular, what problem it solves, and what *problem* it does **not** solve.

#### case 1 —  `std::function` isn't good enough for executing things in different threads

```cpp
std::function<int(int,int)> f { add };
```

Once we have `f`, we can execute it, in the same thread, like:

```cpp
int result = f(1, 2); //note we can get the result here
```

Or, in a different thread, like this:

```cpp
std::thread t { std::move(f), 3, 4 };
t.join();
```

If we see carefully, we realize that executing `f` in a different thread creates a new problem: **how do we get the result of the function?** Executing `f` in the same thread does not have that problem — we get the result as returned value, but when executed it in a different thread, we don't have any way to get the result. That is exactly what is solved by `std::packaged_task`.

#### case 2 — `std::packaged_task` solves the problem which `std::function` does not solve

In particular, it creates a channel between threads to send the result to the other thread. Apart from that, it is more or less same as `std::function`.

```cpp
std::packaged_task<int(int,int)> f { add }; // almost same as before

std::future<int> channel = f.get_future();  // get the channel
    
std::thread t{ std::move(f), 30, 40 }; // same as before
t.join();  // same as before
    
int result = channel.get(); // problem solved: get the result from the channel
```

Now you see how `std::packaged_task` solves the problem which is left unsolved by `std::function`. That however does not mean that `std::packaged_task` has to be executed in a different thread. You can execute it in the same thread as well, just like `std::function`, though you will still get the result from the channel.

```cpp
std::packaged_task<int(int,int)> f { add }; // same as before
std::future<int> channel = f.get_future(); // same as before
    
f(10, 20); // execute it in the current thread !!

int result = channel.get(); // same as before
```

So fundamentally `std::function` and `std::packaged_task` are similar kind of thing: they simply wrap callable entity, with one difference: **`std::packaged_task` is multithreading-friendly, because it provides a channel through which it can pass the result to other threads**. Both of them do NOT execute the wrapped callable entity by themselves. One needs to *invoke* them, either in the same thread, or in another thread, to execute the wrapped callable entity. So basically there are two kinds of thing in this space:

- **what is executed** i.e regular functions, `std::function`, `std::packaged_task`, etc.
- **how/where is executed** i.e threads, thread pools, executors, etc.

#### case 3: `std::async` is an entirely different thing

It's a different thing because it combines *what-is-executed* with *how/where-is-executed*.

```cpp
std::future<int> fut = std::async(add, 100, 200);
int result = fut.get();
```

Note that in this case, the future created has an associated executor, which means that the future will complete at some point as there is someone executing things behind the scene. However, in case of the future created by `std::packaged_task`, there is not necessarily an executor and that future may never complete if the created task is *never* given to any executor.

Hope that helps you understand how things work behind the scene. See [the online demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9291373dc09dddc).

## The difference between two kinds of `std::future`

Well, at this point, it becomes pretty much clear that there are two kinds of `std::future` which can be created:

- One kind can be created by `std::async`. Such future has an associated executor and thus can complete.
- Other kind can be created by `std::packaged_task` or things like that. Such future does not necessarily have an associated executor and thus may or may not complete.

Since, in the second case the future does not necessarily have an associated executor, its destructor is *not* designed for its completion/wait because it may never complete:

```cpp
 {
   std::packaged_task<int(int,int)> f { add };
 
   std::future<int> fut = f.get_future(); 

 } // fut goes out of scope, but there is no point 
   // in waiting in its destructor, as it cannot complete 
   // because as `f` is not given to any executor.
```

Hope this answer helps you understand things from a different perspective.

Comment: Adding some information about `std::promise` will also help prospective readers.

Comment: @Ajay: The answer is already too long. So I refrained myself from adding more stuff. For curious readers who want to understand how `std::promise` and `std::future` work together, the answers in this topic are awesome: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004273/what-is-stdpromise .. and this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12620186/futures-vs-promises

Comment: Wonderfully educational.

Answer (score 1):

The change in behaviour is due to the difference between `std::thread` and `std::async`.

In the first example, you have created a daemon thread by detaching. Where you print `std::cout << "The countdown lasted for " << std::endl;` in your main thread, may occur before, during or after the print statements inside the `countdown` thread function. Because the main thread does not await the spawned thread, you will likely not even see all of the print outs.

In the second example, you launch the thread function with the `std::launch::deferred` policy. The [behaviour for std::async](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) is:

> If the async policy is chosen, the associated thread completion synchronizes-with the successful return from the first function that is waiting on the shared state, **or with the return of the last function that releases the shared state**, whichever comes first.

In this example, you have two futures for the same shared state. Before their dtors are called when exiting main, the async task must complete. Even if you had not explicitly defined any futures, the temporary future that gets created and destroyed (returned from the call to `std::async`) will mean that the task completes before the main thread exits.

---

[Here](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2013/03/stdfutures-from-stdasync-arent-special.html) is a great blog post by Scott Meyers, clarifying the behaviour of `std::future` & `std::async`.

[Related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30810305/confusion-about-threads-launched-by-stdasync-with-stdlaunchasync-parameter).