# Why does ~future block when created by std::async and not when created by others

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, c++14, libc++

`std::async` returns:

> An object of type `future<result_of_t<decay_t<F>(decay_t<Args>...)>>`
> that refers to the shared state created by this call to async. [ Note:
> If a future obtained from `std::async` is moved outside the local scope,
> other code that uses the future must be aware that the future
> destructor may block for the shared state to become ready. — end note
> ]

The returned `std::future<>` blocks on destruction until the value is available.
However the *normal* destructor of `std::future<>` does not block:

> ~future();
>
> Effects:
>
> — releases any shared state (30.6.4);
>
> — destroys
> *this.

As such the `std::future<int>`s in the the following example behave differently, even though they have the same type. Note, that this example does not trigger the block-on-destruction behaviour.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    using namespace std::literals;
    // get a std::future<> by std::async<>();
    std::future<int> BlockingFuture = std::async([]() {std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s); return 1; });

    // get a std::future<> by packaged_task<>
    std::packaged_task<int()> task([]() {std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s); return 2; });
    std::future<int>          NonBlockingFuture = task.get_future();
    std::thread               task_thread(std::move(task));

    std::cout << "BlockingFuture.get(): " << BlockingFuture.get() << std::endl
              << "NonBlockingFuture.get(): " << NonBlockingFuture.get() << std::endl;

    task_thread.join();
    return 0;
}
```

What does `std::async<>` do to the `std::future<>` to make it block on destruction?

I already know why `std::async` is designed this way - I want to know how it works internally.
See this document for the motivations behind `std::async`: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3451.pdf.

I cited from this draft: http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf

Comment: Which implementation?  There are at least 3 major std implementations, and the standard does not specify how this feature works.

Comment: I use gcc 10.2 with the standard library shipped with it

Comment: `std::future` is really bad. really. for "futures" that also support `co_await`, executors and whatnot, you can use my [concurrencpp](https://github.com/David-Haim/concurrencpp)

Comment: Please see this question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63843676/why-stdfuture-is-different-returned-from-stdpackaged-task-and-stdasync